# How to resolve local hostnames in ubuntu 22 not using avahi?

Tags: networking, dns

what would be another option to resolve hostnames in my LAN without avahi? It's is for a DCHP lan, so put manual hosts on ubuntu is not a option.

Comment: Are you actually using Ubuntu Core 22 or did you use the wrong version info?